# Docker - container with multiple images

Tags: image, rabbitmq, containers, docker

I wanted to make a Dockerfile with multiple images to run in one container.

What is the best method to go about this? Below is a list of what I wanted to run in a single container. I have not have any luck with making a Dockerfile with all of these included.

- MySQL Server
- RabbitMQ
- Java8
- Node.js
- Xvfb
- Firefox
- Chrome

This is what I have so far, can I get a few tips

```
FROM stackbrew/ubuntu:12.04
MAINTAINER 
# Update the repository sources list #RUN apt-get update  
# My SQL Server ############### 
RUN apt-get 
update -qq && apt-get 
install -y mysql-server-5.5 
ADD my.cnf /etc/mysql/conf.d/my.cnf 
RUN chmod 664 /etc/mysql/conf.d/my.cnf
ADD run /usr/local/bin/run 
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/run  V
OLUME ["/var/lib/mysql"] 
EXPOSE 3306
CMD ["/usr/local/bin/run"]
```

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far. That will help people answer your question better and provides a better learning experience for you.

Answer (score 7):

You cannot have "multiple images to run in one container", that wouldn't make sense.

But you can write a *Dockerfile* to create an image that will install all the services you mentionned. Example (Ubuntu/Debian distribution) :

```
[...header...]
FROM stackbrew/ubuntu:12.04 #or use ubuntu-upstart:12.04
MAINTAINER BPetkov  

# Update the repository sources list
RUN apt-get update -qq 

# Mysql
RUN apt-get install -y mysql-server-5.5  
ADD my.cnf /etc/mysql/conf.d/my.cnf 
RUN chmod 664 /etc/mysql/conf.d/my.cnf 
ADD run /usr/local/bin/run 
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/run  

# Other stuff
RUN apt-get -y install rabbitmq
RUN apt-get -y install nodejs
[...]
VOLUME ["/var/lib/mysql"] 
EXPOSE 3306 
EXPOSE .......
CMD ["/sbin/init"]
```

Then you would have to get all of them started automatically when the container starts.

You can use a process manager such as [supervisord](http://supervisord.org/) (Docker documentation [here](http://docs.docker.io/examples/using_supervisord/)).

Alternatively, you could use a regular init system, check this base image : [ubuntu-upstart](https://index.docker.io/_/ubuntu-upstart/). This one would allow you to only have to install the packages in your Dockerfile and get them started automatically without any effort, by specifying **/sbin/init** as `EntryPoint` or `CMD` in your Dockerfile.

Comment: this is what I had so far



`code
FROM stackbrew/ubuntu:12.04
MAINTAINER BPetkov

# Update the repository sources list
#RUN apt-get update

# My SQL Server
###############
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y mysql-server-5.5

ADD my.cnf /etc/mysql/conf.d/my.cnf
RUN chmod 664 /etc/mysql/conf.d/my.cnf
ADD run /usr/local/bin/run
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/run

VOLUME ["/var/lib/mysql"]
EXPOSE 3306
CMD ["/usr/local/bin/run"] 
`

Comment: Thanks for the help, I still cant really figure out how to do this, the dockerfile will not build.

Answer (score 2):

The feature you're looking for is [Docker Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/overview/).

Comment: Compose creates multiple container  with 1 - 1 images which is not the same. We can communicate with each containers as well but it wont help in scal . Can you kubernetes or swarn to mange it