# Add camunda-bpm-wildfly with activemq and run in same docker container

Tags: java, docker, activemq-classic, wildfly-10, camunda

I want to add camunda-bpm-wildfly with active mq and run in same docker container.

First I added them to two containers and tried to run as follows. It was OK.

**1. Running camunda-bpm-wildfly.**

**Dockerfile :**

```
FROM camunda/camunda-bpm-platform:wildfly-latest
ADD standalone.xml standalone/configuration/
ADD bin/ bin/
ADD fusepatch/ fusepatch/
ADD modules/ modules/
ADD hawtio-wildfly-1.5.3.war standalone/deployments/
```

**Commands :**

```
docker build my-wildfly .
docker images
sudo docker run -d --name my-wildfly --net="host" -p 7070:7070 my-wildfly
```

**2. Running activemq.**

**Dockerfile :**

```
FROM webcenter/activemq:latest
```

**Commands :**

```
docker build amq-alone .
docker images
docker run --name='amq-alone' -d -p 8161:8161 -p 61616:61616 -p 61613:61613 amq-alone
```

Then I searched for a way to add two images to the same container and noted that we can't add multiple images to the same container[Ref : [Docker - container with multiple images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23636243/docker-container-with-multiple-images]).

Then I downlaoded the activemq and I tried to extend it as follows.
It builds correctly and when I run also it runs correctly. But only wildfly runs in port 7070 not the activemq.

**Dockerfile :**

```
FROM camunda/camunda-bpm-platform:wildfly-latest
ADD standalone.xml standalone/configuration/
ADD bin/ bin/
ADD fusepatch/ fusepatch/
ADD modules/ modules/
ADD hawtio-wildfly-1.5.3.war standalone/deployments/
ADD apache-activemq-5.15.2/ apache-activemq-5.15.2/
RUN apache-activemq-5.15.2/bin/activemq start
```

**Commands :**

```
docker build my-wildfly-amq .
docker images
sudo docker run -d --name my-wildfly-amq --net="host" -p 7070:7070 -p 8161:8161 -p 61616:61616 -p 61613:61613 my-wildfly-amq
```

**Log :**

```
me@my-pc:~/$ docker build -t=my-wildfly-amq .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  375.8MB
Step 1/8 : FROM camunda/camunda-bpm-platform:wildfly-latest
 ---> 274d119b1660
Step 2/8 : ADD standalone.xml standalone/configuration/
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 41c2f6d423ec
Step 3/8 : ADD bin/ bin/
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 27c1952f442e
Step 4/8 : ADD fusepatch/ fusepatch/
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 66419d22d6b7
Step 5/8 : ADD modules/ modules/
 ---> bbdee5ab8ea2
Step 6/8 : ADD hawtio-wildfly-1.5.3.war standalone/deployments/
 ---> 237821cdb2c8
Step 7/8 : ADD apache-activemq-5.15.2/ apache-activemq-5.15.2/
 ---> 309b552b5150
Step 8/8 : RUN apache-activemq-5.15.2/bin/activemq start
 ---> Running in ce0e55cfd13b
INFO: Loading '/camunda/apache-activemq-5.15.2//bin/env'
INFO: Using java '/usr/bin/java'
INFO: Starting - inspect logfiles specified in logging.properties and log4j.properties to get details
INFO: pidfile created : '/camunda/apache-activemq-5.15.2//data/activemq.pid' (pid '46')
 ---> f903dc0b2db5
Removing intermediate container ce0e55cfd13b
Successfully built f903dc0b2db5
Successfully tagged my-wildfly-amq:latest
```

What am I missing here? How to add active mq with the camunda-bpm-wildfly running in same docker container?

**UPDATE#1 :** 
With the @bluescore 's answer I tried to use CMD as follows and it worked. Both activemq and wildfly was started. But one problem is there. Normally when we start camunda-bpm-wildfly we invokes start-camunda.sh (not the wildfly bin/standalone.sh). But here I can't see that file in -ti mode also. How to start the camunda as the image starts itself? (I checked in the [dockerhub](https://hub.docker.com/r/camunda/camunda-bpm-platform/) and [github](https://github.com/camunda/docker-camunda-bpm-platform/blob/master/README.md) also but couldn't find a tip)

**Dockerfile :**

```
FROM camunda/camunda-bpm-platform:wildfly-latest
ADD standalone.xml standalone/configuration/
ADD bin/ bin/
ADD fusepatch/ fusepatch/
ADD modules/ modules/
ADD hawtio-wildfly-1.5.3.war standalone/deployments/
ADD apache-activemq-5.15.2/ apache-activemq-5.15.2/
ADD my-wildfly-amq.sh my-wildfly-amq.sh
CMD bash my-wildfly-amq.sh
```

**my-wildfly-amq.sh**

```
apache-activemq-5.15.2/bin/activemq start
bin/standalone.sh
```

- Docker version 17.09.0-ce
- Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 3):

You're misunderstanding how RUN works. Use an [ENTRYPOINT](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint) or [CMD](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd) script in place of the final RUN command of the container you extended. RUN executes a command during a build, not during a `docker run`. CMD and ENTRYPOINT tell the container what to execute when it's actually ran.

Check out the [Dockerfile](https://github.com/camunda/docker-camunda-bpm-platform/blob/master/Dockerfile) for the camunda-bpm-platform image you're using as a base. Notice that CMD at the end, which executes a shell script.

If you want to run both ActiveMQ and wildfly, you should write a shell script that runs both of them, then replace your final RUN with a CMD or ENTRYPOINT to execute that script. Something like:

`CMD ["/usr/local/bin/your_script.sh"]`

When your container starts up with `docker run`, this script will run.

Comment: Thanks bluescores!  With your answer, I tried to use CMD as follows and it worked. Both activemq and wildfly was started. But one problem is there. Normally when we start camunda-bpm-wildfly we invokes start-camunda.sh (not the wildfly bin/standalone.sh). But here I can't see that file in -ti mode also. How to start the camunda as the image starts itself? (I checked in the dockerhub and github also but couldn't find a tip)

Comment: Perhaps it's my ignorance with camunda/wildfly, but I don't understand the problem you're facing now. You said both activemq and wildfly started as expected, but you're asking how to start camunda as the image itself starts? Is camunda != wildfly? Anything you want to happen at image start can be scripted in my-wildfly-amq.sh and it should happen.

Comment: Normally, we start the wildfly using the standalone.sh. But the camunda bpm wildfly distribution has another start-camunda.sh otherthan standalone.sh (ref:https://docs.camunda.org/get-started/bpmn20/install/). My initial intension was adding active mq also to the same container that camunda run. But when I added CMD to start the  activemq I had to start the camunda-wildfly also. But I couldnt start it as normal way since start-camunda.sh is not found in there. I was looking for a way to start it in the same way that image starts it. Anyway your answer is more than enough for me! Thanx again.

Comment: `start-camunda.sh` does nothing more than call `standalone.sh` and open Camunda's login page in the standard browser, see https://github.com/camunda/camunda-bpm-platform/blob/master/distro/wildfly10/assembly/src/start-camunda.sh. It's fine to run just `standalone.sh`.